# Python: functions for creating and writing two output files

Tags: python, file-writing

I am trying to write a program that reads one csv file and then creates two different output files based off of the input file.

```
file = open("file.csv","r") 

def createFile(data_set):
    output0 = open("Output" + data_set + ".txt","w")
    print >> output0, 'h1,h2,h3,h4'
    return output0

def runCalculations(data_set, output):
    for row in file:        
    # equations and stuff

        if data_set == 1:
            print >> output, row[1]+','+row[2]+','+row[3]+','+x
        if data_set == 2: 
            print >> output, row[4]+','+row[5]+','+row[6]+','+y

    output.close()

output1 = createFile(1)
runCalculations(1, output1)

output2 = createFile(2)
runCalculations(2, output2)

file.close()
```

Output1 is perfect, formatting and everything is exactly how it should be. For Output2, the file is created,and the headers for the columns are visible (so 'createFile' is working fine), but the 'runCalculations' function never runs, including the equations (I checked by putting a few print functions here and there)

There are no error messages, and I've tried changing the variable name for the output file within each function and parameter (everything was just 'output' before). I've also tried closing each file (output1 and output2) individually outside of the 'runCalculations' method. What am I missing that is preventing the 'runCalculations' function from being called the second time?

Sorry if the solution is incredibly obvious, I've been working on this for a while so fresh eyes are a great help. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Add `output.seek(0)` before `for row in file:` in `runCalculations`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `runCalculations` exhausts the data file. That is the problem. It will be beta to open the file and close it in `runCalculations`. It is also better to create the output file in `runCalculations`, see below

```
def createFile(data_set):
    output0 = open("Output" + data_set + ".txt","w")
    print >> output0, 'h1,h2,h3,h4'
    return output0

def runCalculations(data_set, output):
    file = open("file.csv","r")
    output = createFile(data_set)
    for row in file:        
    # equations and stuff

        if data_set == 1:
            print >> output, row[1]+','+row[2]+','+row[3]+','+x
        if data_set == 2: 
            print >> output, row[4]+','+row[5]+','+row[6]+','+y

    output.close()
    file.close()

runCalculations(1)

runCalculations(2)
```

Comment: That makes sense, solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When `runCalculations` is executed for the first time you iterate over `file` object and after the loop ends you are at the end of the file.
That's why calculations are not calculated the second time you run `runCalculations`. You have to move back to the beginning of the file.

To do this add `file.seek(0)` at the end of `runCalculations` function.